# Inline CSS for MAIL template

Tags: html, css, email, templates

Im very new to `html` concepts, i've tried to read others articles/posts but i still don't understand something.
I have to format a template mail in a rails app. The template was gived by my boss.
I am currently converting  html.erb into html.haml so the syntax will be haml.

Since i'm not a front dev someting is disturbing me.

The templates have many lines like this

```
 <td class="headerContent" style="border-collapse: collapse;color: #202020;font-family: Arial;font-size: 34px;font-weight: bold;line-height: 100%;padding: 0;text-align: center;vertical-align: middle;">
```

and in the css above something like this

```
.headerContent {
    color: #202020;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 34px;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Why is there style definition inside the `<td ...>` definition since the `.headerContent` class is already declared in css block ?

I also have keyword `!important` declared in many places, i read articles about style overriding , it is still obscure for me.

Why all style definition are all not just in one css block/file ? Mixing html and css is kind of disturbing

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your email template got inlined by something like [premailer](https://github.com/premailer/premailer). This is a "good thing"™, as some email clients [don't support](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/) `<style>` tags in the `<head>` element. It's ugly and gross, but ultimately a necessary evil if you want to support gmail users.